# adding a class to first div to style inner div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of dynamically generated elements that are all styled the same way except for the first one. If the first one doesn't render, I want the second (now first) to have the styling for the first.

```
  <div class="container">
    <a><div>first</div></a>
    <a><div>second</div></a>
    <a><div>third</div></a>
    <a><div>fourth</div></a>
    </div>
```

I tried to do this with CSS only, but it does not have the desired result.

```
.container a:first-child div{
background:red;
}
```

I've also tried to add a class to the first div via jquery, but it doesn't even add my class:

```
$('.container a:first div').addClass('aaaa');
```

Since neither of these methods seem to work, how can I accomplish what I am trying to do? Primarily looking to fix my CSS answer, but if not possible jquery will work as well.

---

**Use case:**

I am building a sort of schedule profile, but since our framework doesn't support a calendar widget, we fill in the data, then use `Date.parse()`/`moment.js` to get a time stamp. We then compare a date (ie: june 1, 2016) to the current date's timestamp. `if current date > event-date` then the event date doesn't render.

We store up to 4 event dates and I am trying to make it self-depreciating so we don't have to update it every time an event is complete.

---

**Example of Rendered HTML:**

```
<div class="container events" style="margin-top: 28px;">
  <h3>Upcoming Meetups</h3>
  <div class="hugs-post-instructions">blah blah<br>Click on each button to be taken to the registration page.</div>

  <a href="#">
    <div class="square-button">Next Meetup: May 19, 2016
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#">
    <div class="square-button">Upcoming Meetup: September 22, 2016
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#">
    <div class="square-button">Upcoming Meetup: December 1, 2016
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: `a:first-child` should work, btw why did you wrap the div's inside a `a`?

Comment: What do you mean by "If the first one doesn't render"?

Comment: Is the first `a` being deleted if it doesn’t render? Or how is this handled? The first one that renders should always be the first one in the list, right?

Comment: @j08691 will update question to explain use case.

Comment: @Xufox correct, since they are rendered dynamically, if the current date is past the event date, that div is never rendered or created. Thus making the 2nd event date the new "upcoming event date".

Comment: @ether So you sometimes want to select `:first-child` and sometimes `:nth-child(2)`? It’s a bit confusing how the mechanism is actually supposed to work…

Comment: Your CSS shoud work, but please change 'Red' for 'red' in the rule value

Comment: `.container a:first-child div{` should still work. Could it be that the first `a` is still rendered but the `div` within it is not?

Comment: @xufox No, it should always be `:first-child` since, if I have 3 dates written, and the first one is never created, then the 2nd one by default would be the first one to render (which means it's the next event date coming up.)

Comment: Is is the div that isn't generated? The link, the content of the div...what?

Comment: A stack snippet demonstrating part of the mechanism would probably help.

Comment: @Moob Since we have our own backend scripting language, my conditonal is: `{{ if eventdate < current date }} (renders <a><div></div></a> ) {{ else }} (renders nothing) {{ end if }}` So no, it removes both the `a` and `div`

Comment: Then you clearly have something else going on since, in that case, `.container a:first-child div` **should** work....but you say it doesn't.

Comment: @Paulie_D if the event date is less than the current date (meaning it has passed) then the `<a><div></div></a>` does not get rendered.

Comment: @ether - After all the rendering, if you have the above html and css, then the first div will be highlighted in `red` color.

Comment: Can you provide some examples of the rendered HTML? I think what's causing the confusion is how you're generating and not rendering items.

Comment: Yes, I will update question @j08691

Comment: I think, now it’s clear. `a:first-child` doesn’t select the first `a`, it selects the `a` _that is the first child_. The `<h3>` tags etc. were important missing details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, based on your updates, I believe you want the [`:nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) pseudo-class as your selector:

```css
.container a:nth-of-type(1) div {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container events" style="margin-top: 28px;">
  <h3>Upcoming Meetups</h3>
  <div class="hugs-post-instructions">blah blah
    <br>Click on each button to be taken to the registration page.</div>

  <a href="#">
    <div class="square-button">Next Meetup: May 19, 2016
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#">
    <div class="square-button">Upcoming Meetup: September 22, 2016
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#">
    <div class="square-button">Upcoming Meetup: December 1, 2016
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

The `:first-child` pseudo-class selects just that, any element that is the first child element of its parent, not the fist child of a specific kind, which is why that wouldn't work for you.

Comment: There’s also `:first-of-type`.

Comment: WHOOP THERE IT IS! Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could highlight the first `div` by giving them *all* a red background and then removing it for all [adjacent siblings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors):

```css
.container a div {
    background:red;
}
.container a + a div {
    background:inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="container events" style="margin-top: 28px;">
  <h3>Upcoming Meetups</h3>
  <div class="hugs-post-instructions">blah blah<br>Click on each button to be taken to the registration page.</div>

  <a href="#">
    <div class="square-button">Next Meetup: May 19, 2016
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#">
    <div class="square-button">Upcoming Meetup: September 22, 2016
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#">
    <div class="square-button">Upcoming Meetup: December 1, 2016
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```